# Is the Science and Knowledge Publishing Corporation a spam journal publisher?

Tags: education, publishing

I submitted my paper entitled " A new result for divisibility among sum power

divisor from 3 month ago to [this](http://scik.org/payments/jmcs.htm) journal ,I have received in this day this 
message :
Title: A new results for divisibility among sum power divisor function and it's periodicity

Journal: Journal of Mathematical and Computational Science

Dear Author

I am pleased to inform you that your manuscript has been accepted for publication in the above journal. Please re-write your manuscript based on the attached template and send us the .tex file for editing by email within one week.‍
‍
Please note that our journal is an Open Access Journal. A total charge of $100 must be covered by the submitting author upon acceptance of the article.

You can pay the article-processing charge (USD 100) by credit card. Please find the following URL:

http://scik.org/payments/jmcs.htm

We will expect your payment upon receipt of the invoice. Your prompt action would be appreciated. Thank you for submitting your work to our journal.

**My question** : Is this a spam journal or not and if it is not i will 
complet the payment instruction .

**Note**: your opinion always is helpful

Thank you for any help !!!

Comment: Possibly more suitable for sites such as [Academia Stack Exchange](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) than Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: The elementary number theory is very important area in mathematics and my paper is related to this just i would like to know more about this journal and my paper, in any way thank you very much for your recomondation to me

Comment: For what it's worth, a big red flag is that they requested money for you to publish. This is very rare for math journals.

Answer (score 4):

Just Google the publisher. The only hits are on their website with none linked from other sites (very unusual for *any* site). The website is sparse with very few papers and not well usable. Internet searches yield no one referencing a paper 'published' by them. You can find them listed on many sites which say they are a predatory publishing company and not to submit papers to them or pay them anything:

https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/

https://sites.google.com/site/fakeresearchjournalpublishers/home

You can even read about such a case [here](http://gunther-eysenbach.blogspot.com/2013/10/unscientific-spoof-paper-accepted-by.html) where they have accepted a spoof paper that should never be published by any real journal.

So yes, this company is about as fake as they come.

EDIT: As pointed out by mixedmath in the comments (something that surprisingly did not occur to me in the first place), you should always check well published lists of fake publishing companies before you engage with them in any manner. Such a list is [Beall's List](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/). So often do these fake Journals appear in spam emails, [there is even a LaTex program to generate fake papers for them](http://thatsmathematics.com/mathgen/).

Comment: Further, this journal is listed on Beall's list of Predatory Journals and Publishers. They steal people's money.